# How to remove language in Abp.io template?

Tags: abp

I need to hidd language select menu.
In sources Abp famework I saw code, what check count registrated languages. If lenguages more then one, language select menu item is visible.

Comment: There is a way to hide using router service, but its difficult to find route name as its not shared. Let me know if you can find solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

in the web project, you can create the subfolder tree Themes/Basic/Components/ToolBar/LanguageSwitch and into create the file Default.cshtml

You can see che original content in 
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Basic/Themes/Basic/Components/Toolbar/LanguageSwitch/Default.cshtml

You go to comment all code if necessary.

Danilo

Comment: I need to hide few menu item, for that I need to find name of route. Where can I find source of angular module? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is configured on the ConfigureLocalization() of the PROJECTHttpApiHostModule file on the Host project.

See this

[screenshot from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpZU6.png)